# Selecting data based on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a very simply timeseries dataset;

```
     A

01/01/2008 149389
02/01/2008 150438
03/01/2008 154893
.
.
.
09/09/2021 643787
```

And I need to manipulate certain rows in the dataset dependant on what month they occur in.

I've tried to create a 'while' statement but to no avail.

Is there a way of creating an 'if' statement maybe?

It would simply be

if df.index is in October add x

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: have you tried masking something like `df[df.index.month == 10]`?

Comment: oh this is very useful!! thank you! is there a way of doing month and year?

Comment: use and `&` condition like `condition1 & condition2 & condition3....`

Comment: hmm, df3 = df[df.index.month == 10 & df.index.year == 2020]
is getting the error; ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: `df[(df.index.month == 10) & (df.index.year == 2020)]` never forget the first brackets `()`

Comment: ha! thanks, this is perfect.